# How to prevent slim from rendering a page twice after http 200 response

Tags: php, http-headers, slim

When i upload my project to my webspace every page will load twice while printing the HTTP/1.1 200 OK header. This only happens after i began using slim v3 and is not happening in a local enviroment with XAMPP.

I was guessing that my routes were off and would run through the renderer twice, so i put all my routes into groups and added a middleware authentication. But the error remains the same.

The output on my webspace is like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- title -->
        <!-- meta -->
        <!-- some styles -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
        <!-- js -->

        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        Content-Length: 6742

        <!-- title -->
        <!-- meta -->
        <!-- some styles -->
        <!-- content -->
        <!-- js -->
    </body>
</html>
```

my routes look like this:

```
$app = new App();

$app->group('/home', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->write((new HomeController($request, $response))->index());
    });
})->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, Route $route) {
    return Router::handleAccess($request, $response, $route);
});

echo $app->run();

// This is in the Router class
public static function handleAccess($request, $response, $route)
{
    if (!IdentityModel::isLoggedIn()) {
        $response->getBody()->write('Forbidden');

        return $response->withStatus(403);
    }

    return $response = $route($request, $response);
}
```

The expected output i should recieve from my webserver and the actual output in my local enviroment looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- title -->
        <!-- meta -->
        <!-- some styles -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
        <!-- js -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read add more details (like relevant part of the code) to the question.

Comment: I've put a link to the slim part of my application in the question. 
I did not want to paste the whole class in the text.

Comment: No need for including the whole class in the question, only a minimal working example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example